How to manage permissions for IIS sites with 'Authenticated Users' group
Have multiple sites (2) hosted on IIS with PHP. Each site runs under its own application pool, therefore each instance of w3wp.exe (IIS Worker Process) and php-cgi.exe runs under the respective Application Pool Identity.
I have a folder C:\Web, containing the webserver related files. Directory structure is as follows:
C:\WEB
├───AVP
│   ├───1.0
│   │   └───wwwroot
│   │       ├───api
│   │       ├───images
│   │       ├───scripts
│   │       └───styles
│   ├───PHPLogs
│   └───Sessions
├───Dev01
│   ├───PHPLogs
│   ├───Sessions
│   └───wwwroot
└───IISLogs
    ├───W3SVC
    └───W3SVC1.old

I am trying to set my permissions so that each site cannot access other sites files, in case a script on one site has a vulnerability.
What I have tried:
Removed permissions from the 'Users' group on C:\Web, as App Pool Identities are a member of the Users group. Then, I would add explicit permission for each App Pool Identity for it's own directory. I.E 'IIS AppPool\Site1' would have Read/Write permissions on C:\Web\AVP, but not on C\Web\Dev01. However, there is a complication: The C:\Web folder is also shared over the network - This is used so I can edit the webfiles from other machines. I have done this with the 'Advanced sharing' menu, and I have assigned a share permission to a user:
This works, however if I only remove the 'Users' group from C:\Web (& subfolders), PHP instances can still access the files. I have to also remove permissions from 'Authenticated Users' (Which I don't fully understand) to stop my App Pool Identities having access to the files. However doing this breaks access over the network...
What is the best way of doing this?

Believe I may have solved this. Seems like for a user to be able to access a folder/file over the network, they need both Share permissions (See image in OP) and NTFS permissions granted.
Usually the 'Authenticated Users' group seems to take care of giving NTFS permissions to the network users, however obviously not in this scenario.
To fix this, I have simply removed the permissions for the 'Users' and 'Authenticated Users' groups, and then added permissions for specific App Pool Identities to each folder as planned. Then, to enable access over the network, I have granted NTFS permissions specifically to the 'NetworkFilesAdmin' user on C:\Web.
This works fine - not sure if this is the best way though?
